# Stacked If Statement with Index/Match Not Working

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am trying to pull in "Contact_End" to correspond with the ending of the thread of calls. If you look at 127554833506 there are two calls with the same "Web_Form_Thread_ID" and I want the "Contact_End" from the 2nd row of data, not the first. Due to a massive amount of unique circumstances I can't just say "pull in the 2nd row of data's Contact_end". If the last "Web_Form_Callback_Success" is "yes", "NoWorkNeeded" or "InvalidTOAddr" and it has more than one row of data with the same "Web_form_Thread_ID" I'm trying to pull in the "Contact_End" from the last row.

I hope that explains it, because I honestly do not know how else to explain it.

and I am trying to pull in the "Contact_End" date/time if a row is the last row for that particular record (Based on Web_Form_Thread ID).

I got an Index/Match formula to work when separate:

`IF(AND(COUNTIF(D:D|D2)>1|G2=1)|INDEX(V:V|MATCH(D2&"Yes"|D:D&E:E|0))|""))`

And it correctly pulled in the last "Contact_End" time for that "Web_form_Thread ID" when the "Web_Form_Callback_Success" was a "Yes".

I then got it to work with the "NoWorkNeeded", but when I combined the "Yes" formula and the "NoWorkNeeded" formula it is giving me #N/A for the second formula.

`IF(AND(COUNTIF(D:D|D2)>1|G2=1)|INDEX(V:V|MATCH(D2&"NoWorkNeeded"|D:D&E:E|0))|""))`

This is the full formula so far:

`{=IF(AND(COUNTIF(D:D|D2)=1|OR(E2="Yes"|E2="NoWorkNeeded"|E2="inValidTOAddr"|E2="inValidPhNum"))|V2|IF(AND(COUNTIF(D:D|D2)>1|G2=1)|INDEX(V:V|MATCH(D2&"Yes"|D:D&E:E|0))|IF(AND(COUNTIF(D:D|D2)>1|G2=1)|INDEX(V:V|MATCH(D2&"NoWorkNeeded"|D:D&E:E|0))|""))))}`

It is three separate formulas, and each one works individually, OR the first and second work together. Once I add the 3rd that is where it only works for "Yes" and not for "NoWorkNeeded".

Please see the attached image for the example data. Column J is showing the two index/match combined, and what the results are.

[image]

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: The relation between the formulas you typed and the address in which this was done is pretty unclear. Could you add that info using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64141275/edit)

Comment: I tried my best to explain a bit more...I honestly don't know if I can explain better than what was added, or if that's even what you wanted.

Basically...I really just need to know why my match/index works when by itself but when I add a separate match/index it doesn't work.

Comment: Your condition `G2=1` will always put the "result" in the first row of the series. Will be fine for the Contact_Start column, but not for the Contact_End column. You should change it to `G3<=1`. This just to correct its location. I'll take a look for the erroneous outcome (or maybe will come up with another formula).

Comment: By the way i don't think you use of the MATCH function can actually work. I don't think it will check and combine the values from the two columns. It will consider only the first one. I guess that's where the `#NA` error pops out.

Comment: It did work when it was just "yes" or just "noworkneeded" it was once itw as combined. I will try with those changes though! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this formula:

```
=IF(G3<=1,IF(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R["&-(G2-1)&"]C5:RC5",FALSE),"Yes")+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R["&-(G2-1)&"]C5:RC5",FALSE),"InValidTOAddr")+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("R["&-(G2-1)&"]C5:RC5",FALSE),"NoWorkNeeded")>=1,V2,"Success Negative"),"")
```

It is meant for the Contact_End column. It checks if it's the last row of the series (according to column G2) and count if there is any "Yes", "InValidTOAddr" or "NoWorkNeeded" in the current series. If there are any, it returns the value in the column V at the same row. If there is none, it returns "Success Negative". If it's not the last row of the series, it returns "".

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seesm to work, but not exactly what I need, but I think that's due to me not being able to explain the problem appropriately, and not because of anything from you. I'm going to close this out.

Comment: If you want we can try again. What is the problem?